# How do you perform a driven throw with the goalkeeper?

Tags: achievements, fifa-17

There is one trophy/achievement that is described as follows:

> **Offence starts with the keeper**
>
> Score a goal from a counter attack that started with a goalkeeper driven throw

As far as I am aware this is a feature that is new to Fifa 17, so...

How do you perform a driven throw when the goalkeeper has possession of the ball?

What are the control buttons? (assuming default control layout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a **driven throw**:

- PS

  > <kbd>R1</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
- XBox

  > <kbd>RB</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

or a **driven kick**:

- PS

  > <kbd>R1</kbd> + <kbd>□</kbd>
- XBox

  > <kbd>RB</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKM3smKvLQI)'s a video tutorial.

Comment: I'm guessing the driven kick is for information only (i.e. doesn't count for the achievement requirements).

Comment: @camelCase Yap, in case the video is removed I wrote them both.